# How to dynamiclly change file source with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have some img's with some source:

```
<img src="data/model/images/color_01/h_1.png" class="current-image">
```

i need to change their source part after some click action

```
var color_image = $('.current-image')

color_image.on('click',function(){
   var image_src_color = color_image.attr('src').split('/')[3];
   color_image.attr('src', $(this).replace(image_src_color, 'color_02'));
});
```

something is not right bc i have console alert `Object [object Object] has no method 'replace'`, can anybody help? Much thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this using [.attr( attributeName, function(index, attr) )](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex--attr):

```
color_image.on('click', function () {
    var image_src_color = color_image.attr('src').split('/')[3];
    color_image.attr('src', function (i, val) {
        return val.replace(image_src_color, 'color_02');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(this)` should be `$(this).attr('src')`

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are trying to replace something on a jQuery object (`$(this)`), not the URL. jQuery objects don't have  `.replace` method, strings do. You are also accessing the wrong element (I believe), unless you always want to work with the URL of the first image (which doesn't seem to make sense).

Try:

```
color_image.on('click',function(){
   $(this).attr('src', function(i, src) {
       return src.replace(src.split('/')[3], 'color_02');
   });
});
```